# iOS - Cannot process image using CIFilter

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, core-image

I am trying to process image using Core Image. I have created UIImage category to do it.

I have added **QuartzCore** and **CoreImage** frameworks to project, imported **CoreImage/CoreImage.h** and used this code:

```
CIImage *inputImage = self.CIImage;
CIFilter *exposureAdjustmentFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIExposureAdjust"];
[exposureAdjustmentFilter setDefaults];
[exposureAdjustmentFilter setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
[exposureAdjustmentFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.0f] forKey:@"inputEV"];
CIImage *outputImage = [exposureAdjustmentFilter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
CIContext *myContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[myContext createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:outputImage.extent]];
```

But I have got **nil** output image from the filter.

I have also tried to use **CIHueAdjust** with the same result.

Than you in advance

**UPDATE**: I have found solution. It was necessary to alloc new **CIImage**, not only pass reference to **UIImage.CIImage** this way:

```
CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:self];
```

Comment: hi hue filter is working for you... what are the dictionary keys need to be set...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following code:-

```
 CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"old-country-rain.jpg"]];
CIFilter * controlsFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIExposureAdjust"];
[controlsFilter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[controlsFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2.0f] forKey:@"inputEV"];
NSLog(@"%@",controlsFilter.attributes);
CIImage *displayImage = controlsFilter.outputImage;
UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:displayImage];

CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
if (displayImage == nil || finalImage == nil) {
    // We did not get output image. Let's display the original image itself.
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"old-country-rain.jpg"];
}else {
    // We got output image. Display it.
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[context createCGImage:displayImage fromRect:displayImage.extent]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It was necessary to alloc new input **CIImage** this way:   `CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:self];`

Comment: No, you don't need to alloc CIImage. Use this : 
CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:self.CGImage];