# How can i get the distorting mirror effect with an image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, vector, distortion

In my IOS app,i want to use gesture control get the distorting mirror effect with an image.

For example, the normal image is like follow:

[image]

When i pinch opened on the man's mouth, mouth became bigger.
The effect is about like follow.

[image]

Any SDK,code or demo is welcome.Thank first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your given details, it looks like you need to interact with `CoreImage` framework. I would suggest to use `CIHoleDistortion` filter available in the doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004346). It is available for both iOS and Mac OSX.

Currently i don't have a closer sample code but to give you a start-up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519302/ios-cannot-process-image-using-cifilter) is an example on how to use these filters.

Comment: another problem want to ask you, i want one of the man's sleeves Change from straight to bend, which filter can take this?

Comment: My code like that:[filter setValue:[CIVector vectorWithX:160 Y:20] forKey:@"inputCenter"];,Why the point has effect not the point i set?Hope your answer.

Comment: Where do you get effect then ?

Comment: At a strange point,not the point(160,20) of the image view,either the view controller's view.My code at there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526743/image-filtercibumpdistortion-why-the-point-has-effect-not-the-point-i-set